Weird shadow in water simulation
I have made a water simulation but it has a weird shadow that depends on the positon of the viewport "camera". I have no lights apart from the HDRi and adding lights don't change anything. Can someone explain to me what is going on and how to remove it.
Here you can find my project.



So this has to do with the way that EEVEE is faking refractions. since it's using screen space to determine what to refract it can't see behind the character in the water. In order to make this more subtle as well as resolve the hdri becoming visible at the bottom edge of the screen here are some settings to tweak: most importantly in your water material go to settings > refraction depth: change from 0.0m to something like 0.01m to 0.05m. in the render tab > Screen Space Reflections > Edge fading set to 0 (this will get rid of the fading at the edge of the screen, play with Clamp try a low value of like .1 to .5, play with Thickness. Hopefully that helps!
